# *= operation in Common Lisp

Tags: c, arrays, common-lisp

I wonder if there is some function/macro in Common Lisp has similar function as ***=** or **/=** operation in C/C++.

**`incf`** and **`decf`** in Common Lisp can be considered as **+=** and **-=**.

#### In C/C++

```
A *= 2;
```

equals to

```
A = A * 2;
```

#### In Common Lisp

When I want to set a new value to an array element, I have to write as

```
(setf (aref arr i) (* (aref arr i) 2))
```

The statement of accessing the array has to write two times, if there is a function/macro **`mulf`** have similar function as ***=** in C language.

I can write code as

```
(mulf (aref arr i) 2)
```

Then the array accessing statement is needed to write only once.

Thanks.

Comment: Do note that in C++ the `A *= 2` and `A = A * 2` equivalence depends on what `A` is and what operators have been overloaded for it.

Comment: In C `A` is accessed twice whether you write `A *= 2` or `A = A * 2`

Comment: Not included in the standard, but easy to define. See [`DEFINE-MODIFY-MACRO`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_2.htm).

Comment: Thanks @jkiiski, that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in the standard either, but it seems the [zap](http://malisper.me/2015/09/29/zap/) macro is here for that. For example:

```
(zap #'+ x 5)
```

Here is the suggested implemantion:

```
(defmacro zap (fn place &rest args)
  (multiple-value-bind 
        (temps exprs stores store-expr access-expr) 
      (get-setf-expansion place)
    `(let* (,@(mapcar #'list temps exprs)
            (,(car stores) 
              (funcall ,fn ,access-expr ,@args)))
       ,store-expr)))
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is perfect to me. It works more flexible than `define-modify-macro`. BTW, it seems that **`sbcl`** has good optimization of statements such as  `(setf (aref *arr* i j) (1+ (* (aref *arr* i j) 2)))` , so use **zap** doesn't benefit on speed, at least it's really a good approach on code simplify.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this macro (nor this blog). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments, this can easily be created using [DEFINE-MODIFY-MACRO](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_2.htm).

```
(define-modify-macro mulf (x) *)
```

Comment: That said, I would not use it myself, being more on the functional side.

Comment: But this is more like a grammar candy, and doesn't give an improvement on efficiency, after testing. @Ealhad

Comment: So are `incf` and `decf`

Comment: Yes, you are right (after test), thanks again. @Ealhad